# Google Search Console API, URL Inspection

Tags: php, google-api, google-search-api

I want to use the Google Search Console API to check if an url is indexed.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig( json_decode( $json, true ));
$scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly'];
$client->addScope($scopes);
$searchConsole = new Google_Service_SearchConsole($client);
$urlRequest = new \Google_Service_SearchConsole_InspectUrlIndexRequest();
$urlRequest->setInspectionUrl($url);
$urlRequest->setLanguageCode('fr');
$urlRequest->setSiteUrl('sc-domain:'.$url);
$urlIndex = new \Google_Service_SearchConsole_Resource_UrlInspectionIndex();
```

The problem is when I try to create an UrlInspectionIndex to make an inspect() with $urlRequest I get an Exception in the constructor of [vendor/google/apiclient/src/Service/Resource.php:66](https://github.com/DeCarvalhoBruno/lti-wp-google/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Resource.php#L62)

I don't know what those arguments are. Hope anyone would help me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work like this:

```
$service = new Google_Service_SearchConsole($client);
$query = new Google_Service_SearchConsole_InspectUrlIndexRequest();
$query->setSiteUrl("https://$domain/");
$query->setInspectionUrl("https://$domain/$page");
$results = $service->urlInspection_index->inspect($query);
```